# Memory usage goes high

Tags: c#, memory, richtextbox

My windows application has a Form with just one `RichTextBox` on it. At runtime I am loading a text file into it. The text file is around `18MB` in size. When I run the application initial memory size shown in task manager is `9 MB`. Soon after the `RichTextBox` load statement execute the memory size goes to `164MB`. How come a text file of `18 MB` is consuming the `164MB`?

To further research, I put a `Button` on the `Form` and on its click called the Dispose of `RichTextBox` and `GC.Collect()`. But this couldn't reclaimed the memory to initial level. The memory usage dropped to just `55MB`.

Can someone tell me why I am not getting the full memory freed up?

Here is the code used to populate the RichTextBox:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(m_strFileName))
            {
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
                fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
                rchtxtTextFile.LoadFile(memStream, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                memStream.Dispose();
            }
```

My application would allow user to to load some large files as well which would be actually HTML files. User would be making some correction in the HTML tags in RichTextBox Editor. These files could be of around 140MB. Loading this file causes out of memory exceptions. Thats why I am finding out why whole memory is not reclaimed when form is disposed.

Comment: Could you post the code of your app? It would be helpful to see it before giving an answer to the question :)

Comment: Not without the code, but generally speaking - garbage collection is not something guaranteed in .NET so you disposing an object does not guarentee .NET will reclaim all the memory instantly at that time.

Comment: Is it a problem that it consumes 164MB? if not i would not spend any time on it. but if you want help post your code!

Comment: Some fun reading for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx

Comment: Is this in debugging? Or a built .exe?

Comment: Do you have a profiling tool available? Something like YourKit, then you could easily profile the components which are using the memory

Comment: Yes, if it is taking ~164MB for loading 19MB files, I won't be able to load files of size 80-100MB. That's why I want to understand this behavior to get a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Because `RichTextBox` is a known as heavy control. It needs to create internal structure in order to be able to manage custom formatting of content.

If you need just visualize a text, *without any special formatting*, consider use of simple multiline `TextBox`.

> I put a button on the form and on its click called the Dispose of
>   RichTextBox and GC.Collect(). But this couldn't reclaimed the memory
>   to initial level. The memory usage dropped to just 55MB

`GC` is *not guaranteed* to reclaim everything. `GC.Collect` is just a signal to .NET environment to start scanning for garbage. The fact that relevant part of the memory was already reclaimed is a good thing. The rest is occupied by the references generated by `RichTextBox`.

**EDIT**

Naturally, to properly understand memory distribution of your app, you need to execute it in memory profiler.

Comment: Do you have proof for that claim you make in your last sentence? It could be anything.. 18MB of text is Large Object Heap material. it also stands to reason that the working set of the process is probably large due to the LOH/generation size after the GC expands to accommodate the large object its just put through. My point is that it should be profiled before saying the RichTextBox is to blame.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I don't blame anything naturally. Sure to get exact results about memory consumption one should profile his app properly. My point is that RichTextBox is very heavy control, for reasons it *requires* to have. So if one does not need formatting of text, there are other options to consider, if you need formatting instead, just keep using RichTextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the size of the RTF file (18MB is a lot for text, even *rich* text) I'm guessing that it contains pictures. The RTF format in most Windows applications for backwards compatibility reasons uses 2 formats when saving a picture - the original and and uncompressed WMF (windows metafile format).

Some rich text controls (like DevExpress') support turning this *feature* off.

Comment: Well, I tried it with a simple TextBox setting its Multiline property to True. After loading the file the memory consumption shown in task bar is ~120MB. Less than RTB but still around 10 times the size of text file which is loaded. Is this behavior okay?